# How to make a ThreadPool?

Tags: android, multithreading, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

I am making a map app with `OnClick` marker creation. I am using simple `AsyncTask` class to get the street address of the `LatLng` i clicked so i can set a marker and save an `Address` object into list for future `onMarkerClick` intent, so i can display address into second activity, and of course  database backup in `onDestroy`. Problem is that `AsyncTask` is an option when i create a marker and click on it. If i create 2-3-4 or more, they don't build up into a queue and i lose the first or all of them except the last one. I am reading now about `ThreadPool` and `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` but i really find this very difficult. Is it ok to ask for a simpler explanations or/and a code sample?
Stuff i know ATM:
`AsyncTask` is not an option cause it manages only a single background thread.
`Thread` is harder to implement but gives control to priority.
I need to create a new thread on every click or make a queue of tasks to get this done.
`Geocoder` class was an option but doesn't work for me.(bad formatting, random unavailability).

Answer (score 0):

The Android developer documentation has the appropriate trainigs for [Thread Pool](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html). Using this, you can also [communicate with the UI](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html) thread so you can (in your case) be able to manipulate/update markers and set listeners to it.